# color inputfield websites

Tags: delphi, colors, input, twebbrowser

I want to change the border color of the input fields that i can see on webbrowser. I want to know if i can change the border color when i select them by mouse. Google chrome is a good example. Anyone know this works? and how i can make it work in delphi?

Thx

Comment: Is this really a TWebBrowser question? If so then it's nothing to do with Delphi and is actually an IE question. Are you aware that the input fields in TWebBrowser are actually drawn by IE and have nothing to do with your Delphi code whatsover?

Comment: yes i do know that its drawn by IE, but i want to know how to manipulate it with delphi. Is there another way? the only thing i want is to leave the Twebbrowser on the form and when i select the input fields i wan them to light up with a border around them. That possible at all?

Comment: How would you manipulate it with Delphi? It's IE that is doing the work. Can you get IE to do this? If you can't get the browser to do it then I'm sure you could do it with some fancy CSS, but of course you'd have to deal with all the CSS/IE version issues.

Answer (score 0):

That sort of thing is normally done through css styles. IIRC in this case the style settings for *:focus.

Normally stylesheets would be separate from the HTML page and referenced through tags in the header.

If you are generating the content from within Delpi you may have to use a so-called inline stylesheet: ... tags embedded in the HTML page.

If you are unfamiliar with these techniques, I can recommend the [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) site. More specifically their [CSS tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Delphi's TWebBrowser is a wrapper around the [IWebBrowser2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752127%28VS.85%29.aspx) component which, in current versions of Windows, is based on Internet Explorer.

So it would seem exceedingly unlikely to me that any Delphi code could be used to modify the controls rendering.

More recent versions of Internet Explorer do now highlight the active/focused input field but I doubt you will have much control over which versions of IE are installed on your target machines.

The obvious alternative would be to use CSS styling to draw the active/focused input fields differently.